# How to keep horizontal bottom scroll bar always in current view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two fixed width `div(#left and #right)` in html. There's a `table` in the left `div` with long width rows.

I have to drag vertical scroll bar of **all page** to the end when I am willing to drag horizontal bottom scroll bar of **left div**.

Here's my question:
  Is there a way to make sure the horizontal bottom scroll bar of left `div` always in the bottom of **current view**?

```
<body>
    <div id="left" style="width:40%;float:left;">
        <table>
            <!--many rows and cols here-->
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="right" style="width:40%;">
        <!--lots of elements here-->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: no, unless u make the div also always i the  current view like giving it fixed position. but with its x-scroll bar. i wont be possible .

Answer (score 0):

Use overflow:auto; CSS if you want vertical scroll in any div.